# How to Add "lang" Attribute to a <pre> Tag in python-markdown?

Tags: python, django, markdown, syntax-highlighting, python-markdown

I'm using `django-pygmentes` in order to highlight my code-blocks. I'm writing the contents with markdown and convert it to HTML in the view part. Everything is ok. Now, I want to implement the highlighting side. The Pygmentes package needs something like this in order to apply the colors:

```html
<pre lang="python">...</pre>
```

But, it's what I get when I write a code block in my post:

```html
<pre><code clas="language-python">...</code></pre>
```

Here is my markdown:

````
```python
print('Hey')
````

So, Pygments could not find the element. Is there any way to override any method and apply the changes?

**UPDATED:** Now, I've installed the `pygments` and added this extension to the markdown extensions. Here is my markdown and what it generates:

````
```{lang="python"}
print('Hello World')
````

Output:

```html
<pre><code lang="python">
print('Hello World')
</code></pre>
```

Which is great, but there is no highliting yet.. :(
I also linked the classic `styles.css` file after running `pygmentize -S default -f html -a .codehilite > styles.css` and it linked properly.

Here is my custom `markdown` filter. The problem might be coming from this module:

```py
from django import template
from django.template.defaultfilters import stringfilter

import markdown as md

register = template.Library()


@register.filter()
@stringfilter
def markdown(value):
    return md.markdown(value, extensions=['markdown.extensions.fenced_code', 'markdown.extensions.attr_list'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to add the `highlit` extension in the custom filter module. Now, everything is working well. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can always revert to raw HTML. Simply insert the HTML directly into your document:

```html
<pre lang="python">...</pre>
```

You could enable the [CodeHilite](https://python-markdown.github.io/extensions/code_hilite/) Markdown extension, which uses Pygments to highlight code blocks. Python-Markdown will take the language set on the fenced code block and pass it to pygments for you. No need to use a Django app.

So long as you are using Python-Markdown version 3.3+ and you have enabled the `attr_list` extension, you can assign arbitrary [key/value pairs](https://python-markdown.github.io/extensions/fenced_code_blocks/#keyvalue-pairs) directly to fenced code blocks (be sure to include the curly braces).

````
``` { lang=python }
````

However, that will still assign the attribute to the `code` tag, not the `pre` tag. Like this:

```html
<pre><code lang="python">...
```

Also, note that the default behavior of generating `<pre><code clas="language-python">` is the recommended way to designate the language of a codeblock in the [HTML spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-code-element) (see the second “example” ). One might consider it a bug for a tool to not recognize that method of designating the language for a code block.

Comment: Thank you Waylan. I noticed that I forgot to enable the `attr_list` extension. Now everything looks amazing but still highlighting is not applied!! `Pygements` installed successfully and I created the `styles.css` file and it's now linked to my webpage.

Comment: Even if I change the HTML raw script and modify the code block part to `<pre lang="python">print('hi')</pre>` in the Inspect Element panel instead of what it is, nothing happens.

Comment: Are you sure you properly linked to your `styles.css` file from your template?

Comment: Yeah. It's also in the response list which is in my console and it takes back `200` which means ok.